# Find DataScroller current page

Tags: jsf, richfaces, datascroller

I'm using a dataTable with a dataScroller.
I've added the 'Page' atribute to my dataScroller and put getter and Setters in the bean.

How can I check the current page a user is on in the bean?

Do I have to manually maintain the backing bean value each time a user selects a new page, hits next, previous, etc?

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="renderArea">
    <rich:dataTable id="testTable" rows="5" value="#{testBean.myList}" var="item">
        ....
    </rich:dataTable>
</a4j:outputPanel>

<!-- Get called when clicking on button inside renderArea -->
<a4j:commandButton id="HIDDENRERENDER"  reRender="renderArea,PTScroll" value="+test"  style="display:none"/> 

<a4j:outputPanel id="PTScroll">
    <h:panelGrid>
        <rich:datascroller  for="testTable" maxPages="20" renderIfSinglePage="false" page="#{testBean.myPage}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</a4j:outputPanel>


public class testBean 
{
    private int myPage = 1;

    public void initialise()
    {
        this.setMyPage(0);
    }

    public int getMyPage()
    {
        return myPage;
    }

    public void setMyPage(int page)
    {
        this.myPage = page;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to manually set the `testBean.myPage` . It will automatically set to a new page number when you are navigating back and forth using the `<rich:datascroller>`

To change the page value  programatically, just assign set a new page number to the  `testBean.myPage` in some action method. Then reRender the `<rich:datascroller>`

Comment: Thanks Ken. How can I access and change the page value in backing bean though? (without having the user select a page number on the front end)

Comment: Hi Mcloving .I just updated my answers to respond your question

Answer (score 0):

What scope do you use to call the testBean?

Try this, the paging works only in the first time:

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class testBean {
....
```